Confusion About Bound Currents and When Does $\nabla \times \boldsymbol{B} = \bf 0$
I have been teaching myself magnetostatics for some time with some help from texts by Griffiths, Jackson, and other online sources. My approach is a little unorthodox in that I try to ignore electrostatics and free currents to the extent possible.   Maybe not the best approach but one way or another, I think I have gained a pretty good understanding of the topic.  However, some pockets of confusion remain.
One concept I still struggle with is knowing when $\nabla \times \boldsymbol{B} = \bf 0$  is applicable.  I know it is true for a constant field and for a dipole field.  But is there a general class of problems for which it is always true?
Another related question:  I know that if there are no free currents, then $\nabla \times \boldsymbol{H} = \bf 0$ and we can write a Laplace equation for scalar potential $\Phi$.  But is that also true for the analogous case of the vector potential $\bf A$ where $\nabla \times \boldsymbol{B} = \bf 0$?  Or do we have to account for bound currents in the case of nonzero magnetization $\bf M$ ?  The term "current" is not always defined clearly.
My two main applications of interest are 1) a permeable sphere or ellipse in a constant field, and 2) a permanently magnetized sphere or ellipse.
If these topics are summarized succinctly anywhere in a reference, I would appreciate knowing about it.
Thanks in advance.

The vector potential exists because $\nabla \cdot \bf{B}=0$ always and everywhere. In the static case, $\partial_t \bf{D}=0,$ and then $\nabla \times \bf{H}=\bf{J}$ and wherever $\bf{J}=0$ there is a local potential field such that $\bf{H}=\nabla \psi.$ By local I mean outside of any macroscopic current in a singly connected domain. If the medium is both linear and homogeneous so that $\bf{B}=\mu \bf{H}=\mu \nabla \psi$ then there also holds $\nabla \times \bf{B}=0.$
But if $\mu$ is not a constant but varies spatially, $\nabla \mu \ne 0,$ then $$\nabla \times \bf{B}=\nabla \mu \times \bf{H}+\mu \nabla \times \bf{H}=\nabla \mu \times \bf{H}\ne0.$$ In fact, the so-called bound currents are the sources, writing $$\bf{B}=\mu_0(\bf{H}+\bf{M})$$
you get $$\nabla \times \bf{B}=\mu_0 (\nabla  \times \bf{H}+\nabla  \times \bf{M})=\mu_0 \nabla  \times \bf{M}=\mu_0 \bf{J_b}$$
where the bound current is defined by $\bf{J_b}=\nabla  \times \bf{M}.$
This post may also help The form of $H$ in a bar magnet.

Thank you.  Two follow-up questions.  Does the term "macroscopic current" include bound surface currents?  Or just free currents?  Also,  for the case of no free currents BUT nonzero permanent magnetization $\bf M$ can we write $\bf \nabla^2 A = 0$ as we can for $\Phi?$ Or is it nonzero?

By "macroscopic" I meant "free" currents the kind that flow in an inductor. In the  $\nabla \times \bf {M} = \bf{J_b}$ the vector $\bf{J_b}$ represents a fictitious "microscopic" current. A better way of understanding all this, I think, is by Kelvin's crevices, a needle shaped one parallel with the local polarization $\bf{M}$  and flat disk shaped that perpendicular to $\bf{M}$.

The field inside the crevices is vacuum surrounded by the magnet. In a needle cavity the field is what you would  call $\bf{H}$ with $\bf{B}=\mu_0 \bf{H}$, and in the disk cavity the field is what you would call the flux density $\bf{B}$ and $\bf{H}=\mu^{-1}_0 \bf{B}$. Everywhere outside the magnet is, of course, $\bf{B}=\mu_0 \bf{H}$, only inside is the difference significant.

I have seen some mention of Kelvin's crevice but that will be another several hours of hard thinking.  For the moment, perhaps I can try your patience for one more clarification.   My impression is that when we write $\nabla \times \bf H = J$ we say that $\bf J = 0$ in the absence of FREE / MACROSCOPIC currents, even if $\bf J_b$ is nonzero.   But when we write  the formula for $\bf A$, we have to INCLUDE the effects of $\bf J_b$ if $\bf M$ is nonzero, even in the absence of free currents.   Did I get that right?

yes, that is correct, you got it.

Wonderful, thanks again.

I urge you to spend time to understand what Kelvin's crevices are, they give you a hint of an intuition how The Very Great Lord (The Lord Kelvin) saw these things; and I tell you, despite how the Darwinists have made fun of him, Kelvin (Thomson) was right on the physics of his age. And those crevices will also give a hint about the geometric essence of differences between the various kinds of "vectors": differential 1-forms versus differential 2-forms, etc.
